# Subfigure without caption but with labels for cross reference

Tags: captions, labels

I need to have subfigures with proper labels to cross refer, but doesn't need any caption for them. How can this be done?

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[angle=0,width=0.8\textwidth]{sig.png}
        \label{sig}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[angle=0,width=\textwidth]{sigdc.png}
\label{sigdc}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{ (a) A common caption to all figures}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: What exactly is the `\ref` supposed to show?  If you want normal labels without actual captions, just use `\refstepcounter{subfigure}`.

Comment: . Thank you very much for the replies. I want to refer the subfigures somewhere in the text body for which I am using \ref{given label}

Comment: This generates ?? instead of figure number.

Comment: you cannot refer images without caption. If you like to have only subcaption labels as `(a)`, `(b)` etc, than just write `\caption{}` inside `subfigure` environment.

Comment: In the subcaption package documentation therre is section 6.3 "Referencing sub-figures without sub-captions" (using `\phantomcaption`)

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply.